# for loop with try-catch stopping at first index

Tags: java, for-loop, try-catch, inputstream, bufferedreader

String[] urls contains URLs as strings (code reads inputStream of each URL).

I cannot iterate through any indices of String[] URLs after the first index (index 0) even though the exit condition in the for loop is 'i < urls.length'.

NOTE: It works when String[] urls size is 1. I'm testing it on when String[] urls size is 2, in which case only the first index but not the second is iterating. And I'm only interested in what's between the `<body>` blocks (hence `if (s.contains("<br>")`)

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
public void readData(String[] urls) {
    for (int i=0; i<urls.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i); //for a String[] urls of size 2, only 0 gets printed. 
        //I want both 0 and 1 printed

        String str="";

        try { 
            URL url=new URL(urls[i]);
            URLConnection conn=url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String s;

            while (( s = in.readLine())!=null) {
                if (s.contains("<br>")) {
                    str += s;
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          System.out.println(str); // for String[] urls of size 2, 
          //only the inputstream of urls' first index gets printed.
          //I want both to be printed
    }
}
```

EDIT:
This is the sample of an html I want to read (what each element of String[] urls brings to)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Title
</title>
</head>
<body>
Name1 Age1 Hometown1<br>
Name2 Age2 Hometown2<br>
Name3 Age3 Hometown3<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Throw on a debugger and see how many urls you are actually passing in. Maybe even System.out.println(urls.length), as long as it's > 0, it should iterate.

Comment: Why don't you remove the loop and test it with one URL. After that, make sure to close the connection. And at the end if it works, think on how to complete the whole process for the rest of the URLs

Comment: share the stacktrace if any

Comment: Can you show us the call to `readData`?  Also, please clarify what you mean by "I cannot iterate ..." - what exactly are you seeing that you don't expect?

Comment: @Kevin I would just add that `System.out.println(urls.length)` should be before the for loop :)

Comment: @cno Why?  If it's inside, you get the added benefit of seeing how many times the loop really does run!

Comment: @Kevin I was thinking if the length is 0, then the loop won't even be entered. This way you can see it before it enters the loop if the length really is 0.

Comment: Please can you clarify why you think the loop is only iterating once?  What are you seeing, that you don't expect to see?

Comment: @Lori, looks like loop is fine but you may have problem with here in your if condition "if (s.contains("<br>")) ". Are you sure all url you are passing  contains "<br>".?

Comment: Sidenote : please use StringBuilder instead of +=

Answer (score 2):

I have tested this and your code works just fine. Verify the HTML you are pulling from url and makes sure it contains "br" tag because that's your condition or remove this condition and you will get any html.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;

        public class Main {
            public static void readData(String[] urls) {
                for (int i=0; i<urls.length; i++) {
                    String str="";
                    try {
                        URL url=new URL(urls[i]);
                        URLConnection conn=url.openConnection();
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                        String s;
                        while (( s = in.readLine())!=null)
                            if (s.contains("<br>")) {
                                str += s;
                             }
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Url No. " + i +"\n\n");
                    System.out.println(str +"\n");
                }

            }
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                String[] urls = {"http://google.com","http://google.com"};
                readData(urls);

            }
        }
```